# How do I get profile pictures from external providers using identityserver4?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core, profile, identityserver4

I'm using identityserver4 with Net Core. I can authenticate using Google, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and Microsoft but now I'd like to get the user's profile picture the external provider. I'm using a client with GrantTypes.Implicit and have tried adding a new IdentityResource as follows:

```
new IdentityResource {
    Name = "picture",
    UserClaims = new List<string> {"picture" }
}
```

I then added "picture" as an allowed scope for my client. This is all a shot in the dark though as I'm still trying to wrap my head around identity resources and allowed scopes.

Since I'm very new to identityserver4, be kind and be detailed as possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should already be "scope" in the Identity Resources called "profile" having a set of User Claims- one of which is "picture".

Since you are using ASP.NET Identity, you'll need to insert a record for any given user into AspNetUserClaims table with a claim type of "picture" where the value is the url of the online image.

Clients that have been given the scope of "profile" should receive this "picture" claim when they make a request to the UserInfo endpoint.

If you want to make that picture as part of the id_token, then you'll need to add the "picture" claim to the "openid" scope/resource in addition to the "profile" scope/resource.

(The terms scope and resource blend together a little in Identity Server data model.)

--

To get the picture claim from Google you can do this:

```
info.Principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "picture").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

--

When using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google, i.e. `app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google.Options(externalCookieScheme)`, Google doesn't send the picture claim.

If you switch to using the OIDC method, then Google will send you the picture claim.

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc-google",

            DisplayName = "Google",
            Authority = "https://accounts.google.com",
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = "",
            Scope = { "profile", "email", "openid" },
            CallbackPath = "signin-google",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role",
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have the "profile" resource added and can get the user's name, email, and profile URL but can't get the picture. It's not included in the claims back from Google. In my ExternalLoginCallback method, I have this:
`var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email); var picture = info.Principal.FindFirstValue("picture");`
The email is returned but not the picture.

Comment: info.Principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "picture").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: That's the same as using the FindFirstValue. Unfortunately the claims do not contain the picture. I'm not sure why not though. Do I need to do anything with the GoogleOptions object to tell Google to include the picture? I thought `new IdentityResources.Profile()` in the list of identityresources is all that's needed but apparently not.

Comment: switch to using OIDC middleware instead of the Google middleware... see updated answer

Comment: I updated the code in your example and got it to work. I'm not a pro at StackOverflow so I'm not sure if you'll be able to see my changes yet or the comments regarding the changes. Do you know why I needed to add "scope" to the OpenIdConnectOptions to get the picture? It seems to be ignoring the IdentityResources.